# What is mean by 'single product' in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I saw in one blog they have mentioned about `'Single Products'` in Magento ? In there they have defined them as the products which sold individually. Can anyone provide a brief explanation on this? Are they mean simple products ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe they mean SIMPLE PRODUCTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I'm not familiar with which blog you're referencing I can only make conjecture. But let's give it a shot:

There are really only 2 distinct types of products in Magento: simple products, which represent real-world items, carry stock, etc.; and virtual products. Configurable, Bundle, and Group products all represent ways to purchase one or more simple product. At the end of the day it's all about the simple product.

One can assume then that the author inferred either one single item of a specific product. At the end of the day that product is likely to be a simple product because of how product types are architected in Magento.

**Edit:**

According to the OP the link referenced is a practice test for the Magento Developer Certification. The question itself looks to be a trick question. They state the correct answer to be a product sold individually.

Comment: Check the 4th question of this link http://www.vskills.in/certification/practice-test/Information_Technology/Magento/Magento_Test_Set/Magento_Professional_Test_Set-1

Comment: So basically it means `simple products` right ?

Comment: @Su123 IMO, it means that the product is alone. For example, it is not a product which is related to other products like "mobile" product is related to "battery charger","ear phones", "data cable" etc.. but a single product is not related to any other products. It can be purchased as single.

Comment: Then to what product type is it most similar ? (I thought it should be simple product.) Can you explain please?

Comment: @Su123 that is completely my opinion.. I am not sure to which product type it belongs to though. I think it should be simple product...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If it doesn't match with other types of products then only the remaining type is `simple products`.